# Link symbol coming along with text in tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using groundwork.css alongwith jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css.

The code for tabs is provided below

```
      <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
              <div data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab1" data-ajax="false">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-ajax="false">Tab2</a></li>                           
              </ul>
           </div>

       <div id="tab1" class="ui-body-d ui-content">  
           ....
       </div>

       <div id="tab2" class="ui-body-d ui-content">  
           ....
       </div>
```

But there is an extra link symbol which is coming along with the tabs as shown in the image below

[image]

How can I remove the link symbol after the anchor text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the Github](https://github.com/groundworkcss/groundwork/issues/223), you need to add the class `noicon` to each anchor element you do not want to display the symbol in, e.g:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="noicon" data-ajax="false">Tab1</a>
```

---

The full quote, taken from the link above:

> If you're using the `SCSS`, you can globally disable the automatic
>   semantic icons in `_settings.scss`
>
> If you're doing it on a case-by-case basis or only using the compiled
>   CSS, you must add the class `noicon` to each link to be overridden.